# When inserting time series, why the timestamp is always to be starting time in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: timestamp, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When Apache IoTDB writes data, the timestamp of the data is always the starting time, which is `1970-01-20T23:40:41.335+08:00`. When inserting data, the timestamp is fine if the time series is in the "time and date" format, but if it is in the timestamp format, the result is still `1970-01-20T23:40:41.335+08:00`. How should this be adjusted?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your precision of the timestamp is in seconds. The timestamp precision needs to be consistent with the precision set in Apache IoTDB, which is in milliseconds by default. If you want to change the precision setting in Apache IoTDB, you can set it by `timestamp_precision` parameter in `iotdb-common.properties`, which supports milliseconds, microseconds and nanoseconds.